# Get timestamp in jquery in a particular format without a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I want to get time stamp as follows in jquery `20140410091906`. That is in the format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`.How can i do this without using any plugin.

Comment: Google the Date object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
new Date().toISOString().replace(/\D/g,"").substr(0,14);
```

`toISOString()` returns the date in `year-month-dayThour:minutes:seconds.millisecondsZ` format.

So I just removed the `TZ-:.` from the string and removed the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own format, for example:

```
var myDate = new Date();
```

So if you want to display it as mm/dd/yyyy, you would do this:

```
var displayDate = (myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + (myDate.getDate()) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HL2Rh/)</kbd>

```
Date.prototype.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS = function () {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString(),
        mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString(),
        dd = this.getDate().toString(),
        hh = this.getHours().toString(),
        min = this.getMinutes().toString(),
        ss = this.getSeconds().toString();
    return yyyy + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]) + (hh[1] ? hh : "0" + hh[0]) + (min[1] ? min : "0" + min[0]) + (ss[1] ? ss : "0" + ss[0]);
};
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
function lpad(str, len, char) {
    str += '';
    if (str.length >= len) {
        return str;
    }
    return new Array(len - str.length + 1).join(char) + str;
}

function getTs() {
    var date = new Date();
    var str = date.getFullYear() + lpad(date.getMonth(), 2, 0) + lpad(date.getDate(), 2, 0) + lpad(date.getHours(), 2, 0) + lpad(date.getMinutes(), 2, 0) + lpad(date.getSeconds(), 2, 0);
    return str;
}
console.log(getTs())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x5yDd/)

Answer (score 1):

This will do,

```
var d= new Date
d.toISOString().replace(/\D+/g,'').substr(0, 14)
```